# Is there a way in C to use another's program opened socket, to send packets?

Tags: c, sockets

Is there a way in C to use another's program opened socket in order to insert packet that will be seen as coming from the original program ? How ?

Comment: Hmmm ... would a [proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) suit you, perhaps?

Comment: You opened socket has a some file descriptor. You can try to use it.

Comment: There is in Windows, although the point escapes me. The point of the question escapes me. How are you going to co-ordinate your own reads and write ps with those of the other process?

Comment: @someuser You can try, indeed, but usually file descriptors are process-local.

Comment: I know but I tried it once and it worked fine. Oh, seems like another process was a forked child. Table of file descriptors was a same copy.